# Why isn't data inserted into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am importing over 4,000 CSV files into MySQL. The code I'm using works perfectly fine for about the first 2,750 CSV files -- the data is inserted into MySQL just fine. However, after those first 2,750 files, the data is not being inserted into MySQL, even though (a) the data format / type in the CSVs has not changed (b) MySQL shows successful data insert, no error. What is going on? Could this be related to the size of the database -- it is about 180 GB large after 2,750 CSV inserts. The relevant code is below.

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csvfilelocation' INTO TABLE xxx FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@col1,@col2,@dummy,@dummy,@col5,@col6) set abc=@col1,efg=@col2,hij=@col5,klm=@col6";

$status = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

//If successful insert, mark the CSV as imported
$filename = $csvfilelocation;
if ($status) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE xxx_list SET putindatabase = 1 WHERE filename = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $filename);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Remove 2751 nth and try again.

Comment: @selami Tried that. Doesn't work. Plus, all the CSVs are the exact same in terms of columns, format, etc -- aside from the data in them.

Comment: Might be timeout happening; try increasing it or setting it to zero. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php and maybe `upload_max_filesize` could be at play here but I doubt the latter.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It isn't timing out. The process is running -- it continues to iterate over the CSVs as if everything is working. However, the data is not in MySQL.

Comment: Then check for errors on the UPDATE query, see if it picks up anything and error reporting, if it's related to it at all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No problem there as well. The UPDATE query completes successfully and the data is properly updated in MySQL. The problem is with the second line, the one that does the LOAD DATA query. The commands runs as if it is successful but the data is not in MySQL.

Comment: Is your CSV valid. Have you tried to insert a subset of the data after the 2750th row (say another 2000 rows)? Does your lines end with \r\n instead of \n?

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove CSVs are valid and the delimiter and new line format is the same across all CSVs -- command and \n

Comment: Does it work when done directly in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Fred-ii- These files are too big to do via phpmyadmin, although I will try it with only a few rows. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out why this was happening. I solved my problem by breaking apart the CSVs into different databases instead of putting them all into one.